# Create Menu when clicking on ActionBar-Button

Tags: android

I am very new to android-apps and I couldn't find an answer to my problem.

I created an ActionBar-Button (the one with the 3 dots) for my settings.

What I want to create is such a little "drop down menu" when I click that Button.
For Example: I go to "People"-App -> Click the 3 Dots in the upper right Corner -> a menue with the options "Delete Contacts", "Send Contacts" ... shows up.

I want to create that little menue

I think those are called ContextMenu but I dont'know how to create one. This is my OnOptionsItemSelected, do I have to create the Menu here? and how?

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        //Create ContextMenu??
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: You can use a ContextMenu OR a PopUpMenu. As you want. 
See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html. It's quite easy to use

Comment: Thank you, looking for PopupMenus was an instant success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What you mean is the default overflow-menu.
The Items will be put into the "..."-Menu when you specify the mas `app:showAsAction=never` or `ifRoom` like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_sync"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_sync"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/synchronize"/>

  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/settings"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

The developer pages for Android describe  OptionMenus http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu.

Comment: Try not to use links in your answers. All external links may not be available to all users, rather, to make your answer more effective, post the relevant information from the link in your answer.